# determining existence of non-zero symmetrical matrix that is orthogonal to every diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

i am really not sure regarding this claim(if it's true or not):

in $M_{nxn}^R$, n>1, exists an non-zero symmetrical matrix that is orthogonal to every diagonal matrix.

knowing that orthogonality occurs iff $AA^{-1}=I$, i find this claim to be wrong, while considering the $a_ii$ element of a diagonal matrix.

do you find it wrong as well?

just want to verify before i submit my homework. would appreciate a quick response if possible. thank you very much again

Comment: you should include a definition for two matrices being orthogonal. I have never heard of it.

Comment: Now that I think of it, there is an inner product on matrices  given by $$ \langle A,B \rangle = \operatorname{trace} A^T B.  $$ This is a good one as it becomes the Frobenius thing when $A=B.$ If this is what they are talking about, your question is easy enough; experiment with the 2 by 2 case, that tells you all you need to know here.

Comment: using what you've said and properties of orthogonality and diagonal matrices, i find this claim to be wrong. do you agree @WillJagy?

Comment: @BeginningMath I'm curious to know what you mean by two matrices being orthogonal to eachother. Is it the same as Will Jagy's idea?

Comment: @Servaes - this is a claim i've got for homework. i want to make sure i've marked the correct answer. what i mean is that it is not my definition or prespective, just a textbook prespective :-)

Comment: @BeginningMath This does not answer my question. What definition does your textbook or instructor or whomever gave you the homework use?

Comment: from what i understand @Servaes, if we consider A, B to be matrices, then $<a,b>=tr(ab^t)$

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is diagonal and $B$ is symmetric *with $0$s on the diagonal* then the inner product $\langle A,B\rangle=\mathrm{tr}(A^TB)$ vanishes. There are in fact $\binom n 2$ dimensions worth of such $B$ matrices.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but i said non-zero, so it's not 0s on the diagonal

Comment: The 2 by 2 matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is a non-zero matrix.